# Benchmarking Hadoop on EC2 gives identical performances

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2

I am trying to benchmark `Hadoop` on `EC2`. I am using a 1GB file with 1 Master and 5 slaves. When I varied the `dfs.blocksize` like `1m, 64m, 128m, 500m.` I was expecting the best performance at 128m since the file size is 1GB and there are 5 slaves. But to my surprise, irrespective of the block size, time taken falls more or less within the same range. How am I achieving this wierd performance?

Comment: what are you benchmarking?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to think about most likely explanation first

- Check you are correctly passing in the system variables to control the split size of the job, if you don't change this you won't alter the numbers of mappers (which you can check in the jobtracker UI).  If you get the same number of mappers each time your not actually changing anything.  To change the split size, use the system props `mapred.min.split.size` and `mapred.max.split.size`
- Make sure you are really hitting the cluster and not accidentally running locally with 1 process
- Be aware that (unlike Spark) Hadoop has a horrifying job initialization time. IME it's around 20 seconds, and therefore for only 1 GB of data your not really seeing much time difference as the majority of the job is spent in initialization.

Comment: Could you please let me know in which file should this property go? Because mapred.min.split.size is deprecated in Hadoop 2x. There is no mapred-site.xml now.

Comment: I set using -D, I don't use a file.